# Is life hereditary?

Tags: nature-of-god, nature-of-man

When a baby is born, in many cases the baby will be born already breathing, and in some cases even crying.

According to Genesis man did not come to life until God breathed the breath of life into him:

Genesis 2:7 New revised King James translation.

> And יהוה Elohim formed man of the dust of the ground, and breathed into his nostrils the breath of life; and man became a living soul.

Does the Bible tell us whether God breathes the breath of life into every new person or is the original breath of life passed down from generation to generation.

Comment: This question seems to be asking a very related thing as [my question](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/26572/what-are-seen-as-the-implications-of-traducianism-versus-creationism-of-the-sou).

Comment: Where do you get a "New revised King James" that has Hebrew words in text?

Comment: @davidbrainerd I thought the same thing :)

Comment: @davidbrainerd This  translation along with several others were downloaded as a part of a Bible study program I downloaded from www.theword.org. It is a comprehensive Bible study program offered free on the internet. It has multiple Bible translations including Hebrew and Greek versions and most Commentaries, along with many other informative addons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is essentially the age-old question of vitalism versus mechanism. That is, is life purely a process that can ultimately be understood and explained in terms of the same physics and chemistry that govern non-living things (mechanism), or is there something fundamentally different about living things (vitalism). Or to put it another way, is there such a thing as a "soul" that is something above and beyond the electrical and chemical processes in the brain? Or, Is every life a new miracle of God?

People have been debating this question for thousands of years, and I don't suppose that we'll resolve it here.

The Bible clearly teaches that people have an immortal soul, so to at least some extent the Bible contradicts the mechanists.

Mechanists like to say that the debate is over and they have won because it has been proven that many processes in living things can be understood in terms of ordinary chemistry. Scientists can't explain ALL biological processes, but given time they will figure it out.

I think this is pretty weak. Any serious biologist will admit that we have only scratched the surface of understanding how living things work. It's like someone who is just learning auto mechanics saying that, now that he understands what 10% of the parts in a car are for and none of them have anything to do with radio waves, therefore it is a myth that cars have radios. As all the parts he knows don't use radio waves, he's sure that as he understands more, he will have the ultimate proof.

Comment: I never knew there was a phrase for this thought process--"vitalism vs mechanism". Thank you! Would you happen to have any links on this topic that you are favorable towards? I would enjoy reading them.

Comment: Thank you I also had never heard that term used but will now research it.

Comment: The question doesn't really read "is a new life a scientific or supernatural process," but more, "do we inherit Adam's breath of life, or do we each get our own?" It sounded like the OP's assumption was that humans _do_ have a soul. That said, I did think that this was a well thought out and interesting answer.

Answer (score 2):

The scriptures seem to use breath as a metaphor for life. Life is a gift that comes from God.

Psalms 127:3

> 3 Lo, children are an **heritage of the Lord**

Job 33:4

> 4 The Spirit of God hath made me, and **the breath of the Almighty hath
>   given me life.**

Acts 17:25

> 25 Neither is worshipped with men’s hands, as though he needed any
>   thing, seeing **he giveth to all life, and breath, and all things;**

It is also  important to note that God commanded Adam and Eve to multiply and replenish the earth, so he delegated the power to create life to them.

Genesis 1:28

> 28 And God blessed them, and **God said unto them, Be fruitful, and multiply, and replenish the earth**

The Bible has about a dozen references to the breath of life, and it would be difficult to interpret them all as a literal breath. We can't say there is one breath that is inherited. I think the easiest interpretation is that "breath of life" means "gift of life." With this interpretation, God is the true source of the gift of life to all living people; and since Adam and Eve, mankind has inherited the ability to bestow this gift.

Answer (score 0):

1. Does  the  bible  tell  us  whether  God  breathes  the  breath  of  life  into  every  person?  Yes.

Job 33;4

The  spirit  of God  hath  made  me,  and  the  breath  of  the  Almighty hath  given  me
life.

Ezekiel  37;2,5,8,10

2 And   caused  me  to  pass  by  them  round  about:  and,  behold,  there  were  very  many  in  the  open  valley;  and,  lo,  they  were very   dry.  5  Thus  saith  the  Lord  God  unto  these  bones;  Behold,  I  will  cause  breath  to  enter  into  you,  and  ye  shall  live:  8  And  when  I  beheld,  lo,  the  sinews  and  the  flesh  came  up  upon  them,  and  the  skin  covered  the  above:  but  there  was  no  breath  in  them.  10 So  I  prophesied  as  he  commanded  me,  and  the  breath  came  into  them,  and  they  lived,  and  stood  up  upon  their  feet,  an  exceeding  great  army.

1. Is  the  original  breath  of  life  passed  down  from  generation  to  generation?  No.

Genesis  2:7

And  the  Lord  God  formed  man  of  the  dust  of  the  ground,  and  breathed  into  his  nostrils  the  breath  of  life;  and  man  became  a  living  soul.

Genesis 3;22

And  the  Lord  God  said,  Behold,  the  man  has  become  as  one  of  us,  to  know  good  and  evil,  and  now,  lest  he  put  forth  his  hand,  and  take  also  of  the  tree  of  life,  and  eat,  and  live  for  ever:

Man's  life  is  not  inherent.  His  immortality  was  dependent  upon  his  obedience.  Man  does  have  immortality  with  himself.

1 Timothy 6;15,16

15 Which  in  his  times  he  shall  shew,  who  is  the  blessed  and  only  Potentate,  the  King  of  kings  and  Lord  of  lords;  16  Who  only  hath  immortality,  dwelling  in  the  light  which  no  man  can  approach  unto;  whom  no  man  hath  seen,  nor  can  see:  to  whom  be  honour  and  power  everlasting.  Amen.

The  misconception,  that  man  has  a  soul,  although  widely  preached  and  promoted,  is  error.  Genesis 2;7  clearly  indicates  man  is  a   living  soul.  Specifically;  dirt  +  breath  =  soul (life).  As  in;  how  many  souls  were  lost?

Matthew  10;28

And  fear  not  them  which  kill  the  body,  but  are  not  able  to  kill  the  soul:  but  rather  fear  him  which  is  able  to  destroy  both  body  and  soul  in  hell.

Man  does  not  have  life  within  himself,  nor  can  he  create  life.